# Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a reusable component for file upload.The component works but i need to add validations. It keeps on giving the same error on console "Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute"

UPLOAD COMPONENT-

```
export class UploadFilesComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() placeholder: string;

  @Input()
  text: string;

  @Input()
  accept: string;

  @Input()
  validateFile: FormControl;

  show: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {

  }
}
```

UPLOAD COMPONENT HTML-

```
<div class="file-upload">

  <mat-form-field *ngIf="!show">       

      <label class="upload-btn" for="file-upload" (click)="uploader.click()">UPLOAD</label>

      <input matInput #filename type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" accept="accept" [formControl]="validateFile"/>

      <input hidden type="file" #uploader (change)="uploadFile(uploader.files, filename)"/>       

  </mat-form-field>

  <img class="upload-image" src="../../../../../assets/images/taa/attachment-l-secondary.svg"/>

  <mat-card *ngIf="show">
     <span><img class="upload-image" src="../../../../../assets/images/taa/attachment-l-secondary.svg"/></span> 
    <span><mat-card-content>{{text}}</mat-card-content></span>
    <span><img class="upload-image" src="../../../../../assets/images/taa/attachment-l-secondary.svg"/></span>
  </mat-card>

</div>
```

Finally Upload File Component is Called in appcomponent.html-

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
<app-upload-files [placeholder]="'PAN'" [validateFile]="panFormControl"></app-upload-files>

<app-upload-files [placeholder]="'GST'"></app-upload-files>

<app-upload-files [placeholder]="'AAshar'"></app-upload-files>

<button [disabled]="form.invalid">NEXT</button>

</form>
```

Appcomponent.ts-

```
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;
  panFormControl : FormControl;

  constructor(private fb:FormBuilder){

  }
  ngOnInit(){
    this.panFormControl=new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      'pan':  this.panFormControl
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `panFormControl`?

Comment: question updated please check

Comment: Which line gives you the error?

Comment: its probably in upload component , when i try to assign validateFile to [formControl] the formcontrol doesnt get anything.

Comment: Let's not assume anything. Paste the *exact* error message you get

Comment: "Error: Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute" this is the exact error in console.

Comment: Is there a file name / line number printed somewhere? Also, is it possible to create a stackblitz for your issue?

Comment: in upload component.html its the formControl line which shows error....can you tell me how to create stackblitz i dont know that.

Comment: In my case I used a formcontrol with an invalid name, that actually was another field before where angular pointing as issue. Actually it retrun wrong line number for the error. But the error was that I had [formcontorl]='date' that date not exist in my form gourp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues originate from these two lines:

```
<app-upload-files [placeholder]="'GST'"></app-upload-files>
<app-upload-files [placeholder]="'AAshar'"></app-upload-files>
```

You are not passing a `FormControl` to these two child components, and when in the child component it's trying to read that in:

```
<input .... [formControl]="validateFile"/>
```

The error is thrown since `validateFile` does not exist. You need to refactor your code to what you need, probably you want to add form controls to these fields as well, I would assume.